# Determining whether or not $f$ is one to one

Tags: functions

I am not sure where to start or how to find a solution. 
How can I determine this is a one to one function:

$f(x) = x + \frac1{x - 1}$, for all real numbers $x \ne 1$.

Comment: With $x+1/x-1$ the restriction $x\ne 1$ does not make sense, so I assume that $x+\frac1{x-1}$ is what you meant.

Comment: Since you're relatively new, you might like to know that we encourage users to accept an answer that they found helpful. You can accept only one answer per question: to accept an answer, just click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept! Plus, you get 2 reputation points for each answer you accept ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $f(x)=f(\frac1{x-1}+1)$.

Comment: Thank you, can you expand a little more on you answer, I am still a little confused

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate. Let $y=x+\frac{1}{x-1}$. For $x\ne 1$, this equation is equivalent to $x^2-(1+y)x+(1+y)=0$.

For a specific $y$, the quadratic equation has more than one real root $x$ precisely if the discriminant $(1+y)^2 -4(y+1)^2$ is $\gt 0$

There are clearly many $y$ for which this is true. For the discriminant simplifies to $(y+1)(y-3)$. So the function is very much not one to one. We can use the discriminant to determine precisely for which $y$ there are two solutions to the equation.  These are $y\gt 3$ and $y\lt -1$.

**Another way:** We can be much more geometric. The resulting argument is nformal, but persuasive. (It can be made formal by using tools from the calculus.)

Note that $x+\frac{1}{x-1}$ blows up as $x$ approaches $1$ from the right. At say $x=2$, our function is quite reasonable, we have $f(2)=2$. And for large positive $x$ our function is large. So on $(1,\infty)$ our function goes smoothly from large positive vales, to modest values, and then to large positive values. So it must take the same value at least twice, indeed infinitely many times.

Answer (score 0):

**A different hint**: Consider the [definition of a one-to-one function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function):

If $f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b$, then $f$ is one-to-one.